TanStack-query v5: best way to filter by using cached data

There is fetched data from server.
I want to reuse the data without fetching again.
Note that in the useMovieByCategory(), I call useMovies() to "reuse" the cached data. I wonder if it's a right approach and efficient way.
using select inside of useQuery will make fetch again. So this is not a desired since I just need to filter data.
What do you think?

// useMovie.js

// fetch
export const useMovies = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['movies'],
    queryFn: () => getMovies(),  // fetch movie data
  })
}

// filter
export const useMovieByCategory = (category: string) => {
  const {data} = useMovies();

  return data?.movies?.filter((m) => m.category === category);
}

Then I use them across my app
// componentA
const {data} = useMovies();

{data.map(() => ...)} // display movie list

// componentB
const {data} = useMovieByCategory();

{data.map(() => ...)} // display filtered movie list



Using select does not trigger a refetch. Mounting a new instance of a useQuery is what is triggering the refetch, if you want to avoid the refetch you can set the staleTime higher. You can do it like this
    export const useTodos = (select) => {
      return useQuery({
        queryKey: ['todos'],
        queryFn: fetchTodos,
        select,
        staleTime: Infinity
      })
    }
    
    export const useTodoCount = () => {
      return useTodos((data) => data.length)
    }

If that's not convenient for you, you can always use the getQueryData function but it's not recommended because it does not create a subscription.
    const data = queryClient.getQueryData(queryKey)
    const filteredData = data?.filter(...)

My advice is that you set the staleTime to something like 5 seconds or so. Alternatively you could try:
    export const useTodos = (select) => {
      return useQuery({
        queryKey: ['todos'],
        queryFn: fetchTodos,
        select,
        refetchOnMount: false
      })
    }
    
    export const useTodoCount = () => {
      return useTodos((data) => data.length)
    }

Which is going to prevent the refetch regardless of the data being stale or not.
